# How to cross compile OpenCV for the Raspberry PI Zero?

Tags: pi-zero, opencv

Hi so I've got a camera module for my Pi Zero and wanted to play around with OpenCV and Python.

Looking around google, if found a few guides to get OpenCV to a Raspberry but most included to either download some compiled code form some random guys github or to compile on the raspberry pi (48h+ no thank you).

Since I did not wanted to do either of these options I looked further and found this [guide](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/12/18/cross-compile-opencv-raspberry-pi-raspbian/) on cross-compiling OpenCV for Raspberry PI.

I followed it, but later realized that it targets a PI 2/3 and not a Zero, and results in an `invalid instruction` error on the Zero. So here is my question: *What options do I need to change to cross-compile to the raspberry pi zero? Or is it impossible to do that way?*

Original command form the Guide.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/opencv-4.0.0 \
    -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake \
   -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_all/opencv_contrib-4.0.0/modules \
   -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \    
   -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python2.7 \
   -D PYTHON2_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so \
   -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/lib/python2/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \
   -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.5m \
   -D PYTHON3_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.5m.so \
   -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \
   -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON2=ON \
   -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON3=ON \
   -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
   -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
   -D WIDTH_GTK=ON \
   -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
   -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
   -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

I already figured out that `ENABLE_VFPV3=ON` and `ENABLE_NEON=ON` are wrong, but only removing them dose not work either.

Comment: See this great guide:
**https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/08/07/cross-compile-opencv-raspberry-pi-zero-raspbian/** worked flawlessly for me with opencv 4.7.0 on fedora

Answer (score 1):

If im not mistaken you have a compressed opencv package available.

- run `pip install opencv-python` if you need only main modules
- run `pip install opencv-contrib-python` if you need both main and contrib modules (check extra modules listing from OpenCV documentation)

I have used this package for basic openCV functionality such as accessing a webcam.

***Further Documentation:*** https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: No matching distribution found for opencv-python